# asp .net core server serve static file without specify any charset in the Content-Type Response Header

Tags: asp.net-core, iframe, encoding

in my blazor server app (.NET6.0) i serve some static files and show them by embedding them a iframe (so the browser deal directly with the type of file, can be image, video, sound, pdf, etc)

I notice encoding problem on accentuated character on the txt and the html files when its shown in the iframe

I try to insert a  inside the head on the iframe but same result

i notice on the http call to the file these Response Headers

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/plain
date: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 13:15:47 GMT
etag: "1d7f7ff334b008b"
last-modified: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 13:15:48 GMT
server: Kestrel
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Im surprise there is no utf-8 specified in the content-type header, im wondering if this is the source of my problem ?
I expected something like that content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

i try to play with the StaticFileOptions in Startup to change the headers but even put empty option maker the app broken at startup

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { 
});
//even doing this break the app, when the app start the file blazor.server.js finish in 404 on client side
```

So i can't really make something here

th serve my static files, i use a virtual directory on this manner

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Sys.Web.AppliIs.Path_Webdav),
                    RequestPath = new PathString("/" + Sys.Web.AppliIs.WEBDAV_FOLDER),
                    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
                });
```

I notice i don't have encoding problem when i open the link directly with chrome, its only inside my iframe for now, i can't explain that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to override the OnPrepareResponse to add the charset, i don't know why but i have to put ISO charset to resolve encoding problems

```
var lOptions = new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Sys.Web.AppliIs.Path_Webdav),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/" + Sys.Web.AppliIs.WEBDAV_FOLDER),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
};
lOptions.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
{
    var headers = context.Context.Response.Headers;
    var contentType = headers["Content-Type"];

    contentType += "; charset=ISO-8859-1";

    headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;

};
app.UseFileServer(lOptions);
```

for me the subject is close, but if anybody know why i have to specify this charset im still intersted.